# Writing a procedure which gets two lists - lst, dup-count - and duplicates lst according to dup-count (explanation below)

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write in Scheme an L3 procedure *duplicate-items*, which gets two lists - **lst , dup-count** - and duplicates each item of lst according to the number defined in the same position in dup-count.
In case dups-count length is smaller than lst, dup-count should be treated as a cyclic list.

Examples:

(duplicate-items '(1 2 3) '(1 0))→ '(1 3)

(duplicate-items '(1 2 3) '(2 1 0 10 2))→ '(1 1 2)

You may assume that dup-count contains numbers and is not empty.

So i tried to do it recursively:

```
(define (dup-it lst countList c)
  (if (empty? countList)
      lst
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
  (if (= c 0)
      (dup-it (cdr lst) (cdr countList) (cadr lst))
  (cons (car lst) (dup-it lst countList (- c 1)))))))

(define (duplicate-items lst dupCount)
  (dup-it lst dupCount (car dupCount)))
```

and sadly that didn't went well:(

My output was:

```
(duplicate-items '(1 2 3) '(1 0))

>>>  '(1 2 2 3)
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's a "L3 procedure"? The only search results for that phrase are about spine surgery procedures.

Comment: @molbdnilo :
oh sorry, forget about the L3 thing. it's some kind of a "implementation restricts".. 
Let's just say that the code should be pure functional and not using any built-in methods. List and Pair are the only data structures allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [SRFI-1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) list functions, it's really easy:

```lisp
(define (duplicate-items lst dup-count)
  (concatenate! (map (lambda (item count) (make-list count item))
                     lst
                     (apply circular-list dup-count))))
```

The interesting bit is `circular-list`, which returns a circular list built from its arguments (Unpacked from the `dup-count` list via `apply`). This is always done regardless of the length of `dup-count` for the sake of simplicity. As long as `lst` is finite, the map will end and return a list of lists of repeated elements, which are then all concatenated together into a single list.

---

Alternative using Racket functions, comprehensions and the same approach:

```lisp
(define (duplicate-items lst dup-count)
   (flatten (for/list ([item lst]
                       [count (in-cycle dup-count)])
                      (make-list count item))))
```

Comment: Hi, that worked fine!
But i forgot to mention, the code should be purely functional and just practice basic list processing. Does it meet the requirements?

and i'm working on DrRacket

Comment: @ryden Changing out the `concatenate!` for `concatenate` would make the first one purely functional. The Racket version already is.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code gets the job done using vanilla scheme. The idea is that if the length of *dup-list* is less than that of *lst*, then it repeatedly appends the *dup-list* so that it becomes longer than *lst*, and therefore it becomes "circular".

```
(define (duplicate-items lst dup-count)
(let ((dupc (if (< (length dup-count) (length lst))
              (append-times dup-count (+ 1 (quotient (length lst) (length dup-count)))) ; make the length of dupc bigger than lst)
              dup-count)))
   (define (dup-items z dc res)
     (if (null? z)
         res
         (dup-items (cdr z) (cdr dc) (append (append-times (cons (car z) '()) (car dc)) res))
     )) (reverse (dup-items lst dupc '())))
)

(define (append-times items n) ; append a list n times for making dup-count have sufficient length
  (define (iter z a res) ; this proc is also used for duplicating the items in lst
    (if (= a 0)
        res
        (iter z (- a 1) (append z res))
    )
  )
  (iter items n '())
)

(define (reverse lst)
  (define (iter z result)
    (if (null? z)
        result
        (iter (cdr z) (cons (car z) result))))
  (iter lst '())
)

(define (length items)
  (if (null? items)
      0
      (+ 1 (length (cdr items))))
)
```

Some examples:

```
(duplicate-items (list 1 2 3 4 5) (list 1 2 3))

;Value: (1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5)

(duplicate-items (list 1 2 3 4 5) (list 1 0))

;Value: (1 3 5)
```